# Adaptive Card horizontal alignment property to "Center" or "Right" is not working in MS Teams on iOS mobile app

Tags: c#, ios, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We have an issue with "Horizontal alignment" property in the following adaptive elements: AdaptiveColumn, AdaptiveTextBlock and AdaptiveImage. Setting this property to "Center" or "Right" causing major design issues(see the attached images).

Original:

[image: original icon without alignment]

"Right" alignment:

[image: same icon after alignment to "Right"]

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.2",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "ColumnSet",
          "columns": [
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": 15,
              "items": []
            },
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": 15,
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "Image",
                  "url": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-9/100/arrow-9-512.png",
                  "width": "30px",
                  "height": "24px"
                }
              ],
              "verticalContentAlignment": "Center",
              "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Previous"
              },
              "horizontalAlignment": "Left"
            },
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": 40,
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "Image",
                  "size": "Large",
                  "url": "https://aboutflowers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/AboutFlowers_S600Alstroemera_SymphonyMorita_Esmeralda.jpg",
                  "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": 15,
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "Image",
                  "url": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-9/100/arrow-10-512.png",
                  "width": "30px",
                  "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                  "height": "24px"
                }
              ],
              "verticalContentAlignment": "Center",
              "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Next"
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": 15,
              "items": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Image1",
      "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
}
```

The same design works properly on Android and Desktop client.

Comment: Could you please share the adaptive card json so we can test it at our end?

Comment: Yes, I added the JSON to the question above. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Is my answer acceptable? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: We have opened a Bug for this, We will let you know once this is fixed for iOS devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not for bug reports. You can submit feedback through the Teams app itself or you can have a look at this feedback page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback

If you do submit feedback, feel free to link to this Stack Overflow post in order to provide the necessary information.

Until the bug is fixed, you will need to find some kind of workaround. Perhaps you can try the "center" alignment instead of left and right. If that doesn't work then you may have to not use any alignment. You may be interested to know that the schema mentions the possibility of image distortion when using the `height` property, so you might also try omitting width and height specifications: https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Image.html

Comment: @WalaaAbuBader - Are you willing to upvote and accept my answer now?